# KDB:How to parse a millisecond timestamp in kdb

Tags: kdb

I'm trying to parse the following utc timestamps in kdb

```
t:1605083972601 1605083972853 1605083972854 1605083972860 1605083972865
```

such that it resolves at least to the millisecond. I have tried to do the following:

```
`datetime$("P"$10$string[`long$t])
`datetime$("P"$10$string[`long$(t*1000)])
```

which both return:

```
2020.11.11T08:39:32.000 2020.11.11T08:39:32.000 2020.11.11T08:39:32.000 2020.11.11T08:39:32.000
```

Obviously having it round to the second is inadequate.
How does one effectively achieve this in kdb?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Following function converts unix to Kdb timestamp:

```
{`timestamp$(1000000*x)+`long$1970.01.01D0-2000.01.01D0}
```

Kdb timestamp starts from 1st Jan 2000. That is why unix timestamp has to be adjusted by 1970.01.01 and 2000.01.01 difference

Answer (score 1):

Another approach which makes it explicit that what you have are number of milliseconds since unix epoch:

```
q)f:1970.01.01+0D00:00:00.001*
q)f 1605083972601 1605083972853 1605083972854 1605083972860 1605083972865
2020.11.11D08:39:32.601000000 2020.11.11D08:39:32.853000000 2020.11.11D08:39:..
```