# How does one parse an arbitrary unix timestamp to a datetime in kdb?

Tags: datetime, time, kdb

I am trying to convert a unix timestamp i.e. 1618876798363946752 (~April 2021) into its corresponding datetime in kdb/q. I have tried using the following function. (as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64924009/kdbhow-to-parse-a-millisecond-timestamp-in-kdb/64927576#64927576))

```
q)dt:{`datetime$(1970.01.01+0D00:00:00.001 * `long$x)};
```

However it yields the incorrect result:

```
q)dt 1618876798363946752
2254.09.24T08:41:10.211
```

What is the general rule of thumb and associated methodology for converting a Unix timestamp of an arbitrary length to its associated `datetime` in kdb+?

Thank you for your advice.
Best Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just adding another way of conversion:

```
q)`timestamp$1618876798363946752 + `long$1970.01.01D
2021.04.19D23:59:58.363946752
```

and function could be

```
q)dt: {`timestamp$x + `long$1970.01.01D}
q)dt 1618876798363946752
2021.04.19D23:59:58.363946752
```

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: nw, all the best!

Answer (score 2):

I've slightly adjusted @terrylynch's answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64927576/9364415) to account for the full precision of a timestamp.

```
q)`datetime$1970.01.01+0D00:00:00.000000001*1618876798363946752
2021.04.19T23:59:58.363
```